# How to install specific python version (Termux)

Tags: python, termux

I am trying to install a specific version of python using termux (python 3.5) but it is downloading the latest version (Python 3.7.2-1) instead. Is there any way to specify what version to install?

The command I am using is very straightforward, but I haven't found any way to specify version anywhere

```
pkg install python
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To do what you intend...you can use the following command..

1. First Make Sure that the package version you need to install exists... Use:

```bash
apt-cache madison [packagename]
```

2. If the package version you're trying to install exists, simply run:

```bash
apt-get install [packagename]=[DesiredVersion]
```

Comment: The python version I am looking for sadly doesn't exist, but since this method confirms it doesn't exist (for Termux at least) and it is also useful for the future I'll mark it as accepted

Answer (score 1):

Not an easy way, but you can download source of the specific version and build it yourself. This works for me.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30937467)

Comment: @tomerpacific wdym "this does not provide an answer"?